# How to add days to a date from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't figure out how to add days to a date from Google Sheets with Google Apps Script.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var car = row[1];
    var date = row[2];

if ((car == "Car1") || (car == "Car2")) {
        var newDay = new Date(date + 154);
        Logger.log(newDay);
}
```

I've tried using `new Date(date.add({days: 154}));` but that throws an error about not finding `add()` in the object.

I thought it may be a formatting issue, in Sheets the format is `7/26/2014`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do that, here are 2 of them

1. Knowing that native value of JavaScript Date are milliseconds, you can add `n` times 3600000*24 milliseconds to this native value, `n` being the number of days.
2. or you can get the day value, add `n` to this value and rebuild the date with that. To get the day simply use `getDate()`. See doc on JS date [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Below is a simple demo function that uses both methods and shows results in the logger :

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var car = row[1];
    var date = new Date(row[2]); // make the sheet value a date object
    Logger.log('original value = '+date);
    Logger.log('method 1 : '+new Date(date.getTime()+5*3600000*24));
    Logger.log('method 2 : '+new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+5)));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That did it!  I noticed that I didn't set the sheet value to a date object, which was probably the biggest problem.  Thanks!