# Adding Days to Date - Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to this, so apologies if the answer is glaringly obvious.

I am trying to add and subtract days from today's date.  The idea is eventually to calculate the date of next Monday and last Monday.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035661/adding-days-to-a-date-google-script) which solved my first problem, but the next is perplexing me: subtracting days from today's date works without issue. Adding gives an invalid date.

The code is:

```
function findDate() {
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDay();
   var makeDate = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()));
   Logger.log(makeDate)
   var weekDaysTo = new Array(7); //array of days to following Monday
   weekDaysTo[0]=  1
      weekDaysTo[1] = 7
      weekDaysTo[2] = 6
      weekDaysTo[3] = 5
      weekDaysTo[4] = 4
      weekDaysTo[5] = 3
      weekDaysTo[6] = 2

  Logger.log('weekDaysTo gives '+weekDaysTo[n])   

  var weekDaysFrom = new Array(7); //array of days to previous Monday
      weekDaysFrom[0]=  6
      weekDaysFrom[1] = 0
      weekDaysFrom[2] = 1
      weekDaysFrom[3] = 2
      weekDaysFrom[4] = 3
      weekDaysFrom[5] = 4
      weekDaysFrom[6] = 5

  var prevMon = new Date(makeDate+weekDaysTo[n]*3600000*24); //Converts ms     into days and adds

  Logger.log('Next Monday is '+prevMon);

  var followingMon = new Date(makeDate-weekDaysFrom[n]*3600000*24); //Converts ms into days
  Logger.log('Last Monday was ' +followingMon);
```

The Log Output is:

```
[16-05-22 21:17:58:419 ICT] Sun May 22 21:17:58 GMT+07:00 2016
[16-05-22 21:17:58:419 ICT] weekDaysTo gives 1
[16-05-22 21:17:58:420 ICT] Next Monday is Invalid Date 
[16-05-22 21:17:58:420 ICT] Last Monday was Mon May 16 2016 21:17:58 GMT+0700 (ICT)
```

This is irrespective of the value I add to the date. I can't see why subtracting works fine, but adding causes an invalid date. Changing the numbers added has no effect, changing it to subtraction works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because JavaScript handles addition and subtraction different depending on the types of the operands.

```
> new Date()
Sun May 22 2016 14:45:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
> new Date()+1
'Sun May 22 2016 14:45:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)1'
> new Date()-1
1463928307077
```

In your example, you should try converting `makeDate` to milliseconds before performing addition, either by doing `+makeDate` or `makeDate.getTime()`.

For example, instead of:

```
var prevMon = new Date(makeDate+weekDaysTo[n]*3600000*24);
```

Try:

```
var prevMon = new Date(+makeDate+weekDaysTo[n]*3600000*24);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is extremely convoluted code for getting next Monday. Perhaps it works, but consider a far simpler algorithm. Hopefully the comments are sufficient:

```js
/* Given a date, return a new date for the following Monday.
** If date is a Monday, returns the following Monday.
**
** @param {Date} date - date to get next Monday of. 
**                    - Default is current date.
** @returns {Date}    - date for next Monday.
*/
function getNextMonday(date) {
  // Copy provided date or use current date
  date = date? new Date(+date) : new Date();

  // Get the day number
  var dayNum = date.getDay();

  // Set date to next Monday
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + (dayNum? 8 - dayNum: 1));
  return date;
}

var x = new Date(2016,4,29)
document.write('Start date: ' + x + '<br>Next Monday: ' + getNextMonday(x));
x = new Date();
document.write('<br><br>Start date: ' + x + '<br>Next Monday: ' + getNextMonday());
```

Here's a similar function for getting the previous Monday:

```
function getPreviousMonday(date) {
  date = date? new Date(+date) : new Date();
  var dayNum = date.getDay();
  // If Sunday, subtract 6. If Monday, subtract 7. Otherwise subtract dayNum - 1
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - (dayNum? (dayNum - 1 || 7) : 6));
  return date;
}
```

Comment: Convoluted is a word used to describe my progamming (and perhaps me!) since my university days.

That's much more elegant.  Thank you.