# How to sum up date values to a number (days' sum)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a list of activities with a start date, and a number that specifies the duration in days of that activity. I need to use Google Apps Script to sum those numbers to the date, to obtain the deadline for the activity.

I've tried the solution posted in this question: [Adding Days to a Date - Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035661/adding-days-to-a-date-google-script).

The problem with that solution is that the script editor of the spreadsheet doesn't recognize the "Date" Class, so I can't instantiate a Date element.

Summing directly only takes the date and the number as a string.
Trying the method above results in a `#NUM!` error in the cell I want to convert.

**EDIT:**

I've tried this, where V3 holds the date I want to sum:

```
var fecha= new Date (ss.getSheetByName(camada).getRange("V3").getValue());
var fecha2= new Date();

fecha2.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1);

ss.getSheetByName(camada).getRange("W3").setValue(fecha2);
```

It apparently works, but the problem is that V3 holds `5/13/2019` and the date returned is `4/14/2019`, so it is a day more (13->14) but it is a month less (5->4).

Comment: Show the actual things you've tried, i.e. any formulas, script, etc.

Comment: @tehhowch added! I have a new kind of problem now, it seems. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you've set timezone information for both the Google Sheets file, and the Google Apps Script project. Don't forget that a JavaScript date has millisecond resolution, and is timezone-aware, so if you see dates like "17 Apr 2019 18:00 GMT-6", it is functionally identical to "18 Apr 2019 01:00 GMT+1"

Answer (score 0):

The answer *was* in [Adding Days to a Date - Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035661/).

Three things:

- don't define `fecha2` as new Date(); this gives it no context and instead returns **today's** date.
- let fecha2 be a variable name
- the correct statement is `var fecha2 = new Date(fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1));`

---

```
function so55593876() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("C3");
  var value = range.getValue();
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Date Range: "+range.getA1Notation()+", Date value: "+value);//DEBUG
  var date = new Date(value); // make the sheet value a date object
  Logger.log("DEBUG: new date(value) = "+date);//DEBUG
  var dateTime = new Date(date.getTime()+1*3600000*24); 
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Method 1 (add one day = getTime()+1*3600000*24) = "+dateTime);//DEBUG  
  var dateDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+1));
  Logger.log('DEBUG: Method 2 (add one day = getdate()+1) = '+dateDate);//DEBUG
  ss.getRange("C4").setValue(dateDate);
  Logger.log("<<<<<<<<<<<FETCHA>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  var fecha = new Date(value); // make the sheet value a date object
  Logger.log("DEBUG: fecha: new date(value) = "+fecha);//DEBUG
  var fecha2= new Date(); // note there are no parameters; this will return TODAY's date
  Logger.log("DEBUG: fecha2 = "+fecha2);//DEBUG
  var fecha3 = fecha2.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1);
  Logger.log("DEBUG: fecha3 = "+fecha3); //DEBUG
  var fecha2 = new Date(fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1));
  Logger.log("DEBUG: fecha2 = "+fecha2); //DEBUG
  ss.getRange("C5").setValue(fecha2);
}
```

---

I have left all the `Logger` statements in the code so that you can identify the various values at different states of the script.