# How to pull date from cell and compare it to today's date

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a spreadsheet to manage certification expiration dates. I want to send an email to an employee when their certification is expiring within 90 days. I only want to send one email. I am struggling getting the date from the cell and comparing it to today's date.

I want to send an email if Todays Date + 90 days in MS is > certification expiration date in MS.

I started using a template to prevent sending duplicate emails. I got it working with if && with words in two cells. I am struggling getting the dates to work. I have tried using `getTime()` to get the dates in MS but `getValues().getTime` returns an error.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

var NintyDayInMs = 90*24*60*60*100;
var Today = new Date().getTime();
var expired = Today+NintyDayInMs;

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2]; // Third column
    var exp = row[3]; // Fourth column
    var expDate = exp.getTime();

    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && expDate < expired) { // Prevents 
sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
 interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

My current code results in

> TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object (Date in cell).
>   (line 26, file "Code")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Adding Days to a Date - Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036982/1330560) for a better understanding of date arithmetic in scripts.

> The flaw is in trying to chain the expiry date. Instead of:
>   `var exp = row[3]; // Fourth column`
>   `var expDate = exp.getTime();`
>
> use just:
>   `var expDate = new Date(row[3]); // make the sheet value a date object`

Then the rest goes naturally...

```
var expDate = new Date(row[3]); // make the sheet value a date object    
Logger.log("expiry = "+expDate);    
var today = new Date();    
Logger.log("today = "+today);    
var today90 = new Date(today.getTime()+90*3600000*24);// 90 days from today    
Logger.log("today90 = "+today90);    
if ((today90 > expDate) && (emailSent!=EMAIL_SENT)){    
   Logger.log("send the email");    
}    
else    
{    
   Logger.log("don't send the email");    
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. I haven't experimented much with  Logger.log(). That was a big help

Comment: I greatly appreciate it!